# Python program with permutations too slow,any ways to speed up the program?

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

https://www.ksp.sk/ulohy/zadania/1238/ Link to problem(In slovak)

The simplest english translation:  The 1st,named signlist, variable is an input of an undefined number of "<" and ">" symbols. The 2nd,named n,is the length of signlist + 1,because its the amount of numbers to go between those symbols(ex. 2>1<3,signlist has 2 symbols,n is 3,numbers are a list of the range 1-n+1 exclusivly). 
Im supposed to print out the correct order of numbers for the symbols(ex.  4 3 2 1 for the input >>>.)
My code works,but is slow according to the website.
Commented out is the first version which i based the list compherehensions on.

```
#combinations(ofwhat,howmanychars)

from itertools import permutations
signlist = [l for z in input() for l in z]
n = len(signlist)+1
ListOfCorrect = [i for i in permutations(range(1,n+1),n) if eval(("{}".join(str(y) for y in i)).format(*signlist))]
print(*ListOfCorrect[0],sep = " ")

#for i in permutations(range(1,n+1),n):
#    forstring1 = ("{}".join(str(y) for y in i)).format(*signlist)
#    if eval(forstring1):
#        print(" ".join(str(y) for y in i))
#        break

#x = list(permutations(range(1,n+1),n))
```

Comment: List comprehension is great. But don't try to write everything in one line. It is almost impossible to read.

Comment: I was trying to write fast code,sorry for the unreadability,the commented out code below it is its equivalent.

Comment: Your problem isn't the code.  Think of the algorithm... I am sure you can do better than "print out every combination of numbers and > or < signs until one of them happens to work"

Comment: the site doesn't want you to bruteforce the solution. For instance, if n is first, then only range (0,n-1) can come after if sign is `>`. That calls for a recursive algorithm.

Comment: I'll try that.I thought using permutations would be simple and fast enough,but that logic was flawed because of my hunger.Thanks!

Comment: @PaulBecotte Well, the code isn't great either. `eval` is notoriously slow, for example.

Comment: You definetely dont want to use `permutations` from `itertools` here. Permutations of unique numbers are factorial. So your speed is reastically `n!`, while this kind of tasks require you to come up with `n` or `n^2` time complexity. If I had to guess, it's probably having to find place in those `<` and `>` where lowest number is and go from that. Aso sincce `n<10^6` its no wonder its too slow, sinec you are trying to generate permutations of one milion unique numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ,my knowledge in algorithms is really lacking since i haven't learnt much about them in school yet,i'll study them before attempting this one again,again thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your most controllable source of slowdown is building that huge list.  Instead, take the permutations individually.  Handle each expression in order (which should save time when **N** is huge); alternately, generate a list of all the expressions and hit them with an **all** reduction.

Perhaps better for huge lists is to take the list of numbers 1-n and the list of operators.  At each level, split the list into legal and illegal unused numbers for that operator.  Recur on each element of the legal list.

For instance, let's just assume that you've been called with [2, 3, 4, 7, 8] and the current string "5<>><>".  You now need to accept only numbers **x** such that **5 < x**.  You take the left-hand part of the list and recur on each of 2, 3, and 4.  The first one looks like:

```
place_nums( [3, 4, 7, 8], "2>><>" )
```

This will fail; the next one is

```
place_nums( [2, 4, 7, 8], "3>><>" )
```

See how that works?  On average, you'll recur on half the elements at each level, and prune the dead ends before you have to generate all of the permutations.

Is that enough of a start to let you move ahead on the recursive algorithm?